# acronym option passed at the class level rather than to the (glossaries) package level doesn't work

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, package-options, class-options

I was pretty sure that options (including unknown ones) passed at the class level were also passed to the loaded packages. Hence I don't understand why the following MCE works like a charm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{at}{at}{Acronym test}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

but not the following one where the `acronym` option is passed to the class rather to the `glossaries` package:

```
\documentclass[acronym]{article}
\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{at}{at}{Acronym test}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

This leads indeed to the following error message:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \glsdefaulttype
l.6 \newacronym{at}{at}{Acronym test}

? s
OK, entering \scrollmode...
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \glsdefaulttype
l.6 \newacronym{at}{at}{Acronym test}

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \glsdefaulttype
l.6 \newacronym{at}{at}{Acronym test}


! Package glossaries Error: Glossary type '\glsdefaulttype ' has not
been defined.

[...]
```

Note that the following MCE (`acronym` option passed to the class, but no `nomain` `glossaries` option):

```
\documentclass[acronym]{myclass}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{at}{at}{Acronym test}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
%
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

does work (well, mostly: the name of the glossary is "Glossary" whereas it is "Acronym" if `acronym` option is passed not to the class but to `glossaries` directly).

BTW, passing explicitly (thanks to `\PassOptionsToPackage`) the `acronym`
class option to `glossaries` in a personal class gives the same error:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\newif\if@acronym\@acronymfalse
\DeclareOption{acronym}{\@acronymtrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
%
\RequirePackage{filehook}
\RequirePackage{hopatch}
%
\hopatch@AfterPackage{glossaries}{%
  \if@acronym
  \PassOptionsToPackage{acronym}{glossaries}%
  \fi
}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[acronym]{myclass}
\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{at}{at}{Acronym test}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
%
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that `acronym` is not declared as an option in `glossaries`.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I should have emphasized that `acronym` *is* an option of `glossaries` package. Or maybe do you mean it is a package option but not declared in a way it can be taken in account if passed as a class option?

Comment: I know that it's possible to pass the option to `glossaries`, but there's no `\DeclareOptionX{acronym}` and I believe this is the problem.

Comment: The `acronym` option is defined using `\define@boolkey{glossaries.sty}[gls]{acronym}[true]{...}` (via `xkeyval`)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Which precisely is the problem: it's not in the list of package options, so when evaluating the list of global options, `acronym` is disregarded.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I agree this is the problem, but since the `xkeyval` manual indicates you can use this method for defining key=value package options, I think the solution needs to be provided by `xkeyval` rather than all the individual packages that use `xkeyval` to define key=value options.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I fully concur.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Should I make a feature request to Hendri Adriaens, the xkeyval's author?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I raised the matter at the recent UK TUG meeting, and the general consensus was the mechanism behind the way the document class options work isn't really compatible with key=value package options.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Okay, but what does it mean in practice? That package authors are encouraged to manually add `\DeclareOptionX{〈option〉}` for each 〈option〉of their package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general example that illustrates the issue. Suppose I write a package called, say, `test` like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\define@boolkey{test.sty}[test]{bold}[true]{}

\newcommand*{\test@animal}{parrot}
\newcommand*{\test@parrot@sound}{squawk}
\newcommand*{\test@dog@sound}{woof}
\newcommand*{\test@duck@sound}{quack}
\newcommand*{\test@cow@sound}{moo}

\define@choicekey{test.sty}{animal}{dog,duck,cow}{%
  \renewcommand*{\test@animal}{#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\test@adj}{silly}

\define@key{test.sty}{adj}{\renewcommand*{\test@adj}{#1}}

\ProcessOptionsX

\newcommand*{\test}{{\iftestbold \bfseries \fi The \test@adj\ 
\test@animal\ said ``\csuse{test@\test@animal @sound}!''}}

\endinput
```

Here's an example document that uses this class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bold,adj={giant killer},animal=duck]{test}

\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: The giant killer duck said "quack!"]

However, as mentioned in the comments, these options can't be passed via the document class options. If I try:

```
\documentclass[animal=duck]{article}
```

I get the warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [animal=duck].
```

Even worse, if I try:

```
\documentclass[animal={duck}]{article}
```

I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.123 \input
            {size1\@ptsize.clo}
```

In general, I'm not very keen on the idea of specifying package options in `\documentclass` as it's possible there may be multiple packages that have the same options. If the user is not aware of this, unexpected results can occur. (This is evident by the number of times there is a question either here or on another site or newsgroup from a user who can't understand why their included images are all in draft mode.) In fact, `babel` language options are the only options I'd recommend being passed with the document class options (but only because `babel` doesn't provide a convenient list of loaded languages).

So what are the alternatives?

Packages usually provide commands that can be used instead of package options. Here is an improvement to the package design:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\define@boolkey{test.sty}[test]{bold}[true]{}

\newcommand*{\test@animal}{parrot}
\newcommand*{\test@parrot@sound}{squawk}
\newcommand*{\test@dog@sound}{woof}
\newcommand*{\test@duck@sound}{quack}
\newcommand*{\test@cow@sound}{moo}

\newcommand*{\setanimal}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{test@#1@sound}%
  {%
     \renewcommand*{\test@animal}{#1}%
  }%
  {%
     \PackageError{test}{Unknown animal `#1'}{}%
  }%
}

\define@choicekey{test.sty}{animal}{dog,duck,cow}{%
  \setanimal{#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\test@adj}{silly}

\newcommand*{\setadj}[1]{\renewcommand*{\test@adj}{#1}}

\define@key{test.sty}{adj}{\setadj{#1}}

\ProcessOptionsX

\newcommand*{\setuptest}[1]{\setkeys{test.sty}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\test}{{\iftestbold \bfseries \fi The \test@adj\ 
\test@animal\ said ``\csuse{test@\test@animal @sound}!''}}

\endinput
```

Now if I'm unable to set the options when the package is loaded (for example, the package is automatically loaded by another package) I can specify my options via these new commands. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{test}

\setuptest{bold,adj={giant killer},animal=duck}

\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately there are occasions where the option must be set when the package is loaded, which brings us back to `glossaries`. Most of the package options have an equivalent command or a set of commands that achieve the same effect. For example, the `shortcuts` option can be achieved via the command `\DefineAcronymSynonyms`. The `acronym` option is a little more complicated:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossary[alg]{acronym}{acr}{acn}{\acronymname}%
\renewcommand*{\acronymtype}{acronym}%
\DeclareAcronymList{acronym}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name=sample,description={an example}}
\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{Sample}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{sample}
\gls{abc}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

There are only really two options that absolutely have to be set when the package is loaded: `makeindex` and `xindy`. With version 4.01, you can also use `makeindex` or `xindygloss` (equivalent to the `xindy` option without a value) as class options.

**Edit:**

Note that package options defined using `\DeclareOptionX` also can't be passed via the document class. For example, suppose my test package is now:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\test@shape}{}

\DeclareOptionX{em}{\renewcommand*{\test@shape}{\em}}

\define@boolkey{test.sty}[test]{bold}[true]{}

\newcommand*{\test@animal}{parrot}
\newcommand*{\test@parrot@sound}{squawk}
\newcommand*{\test@dog@sound}{woof}
\newcommand*{\test@duck@sound}{quack}
\newcommand*{\test@cow@sound}{moo}

\newcommand*{\setanimal}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{test@#1@sound}%
  {%
     \renewcommand*{\test@animal}{#1}%
  }%
  {%
     \PackageError{test}{Unknown animal `#1'}{}%
  }%
}

\define@choicekey{test.sty}{animal}{dog,duck,cow}{%
  \setanimal{#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\test@adj}{silly}

\newcommand*{\setadj}[1]{\renewcommand*{\test@adj}{#1}}

\define@key{test.sty}{adj}{\setadj{#1}}

\ProcessOptionsX

\newcommand*{\setuptest}[1]{\setkeys{test.sty}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\test}{{\test@shape \iftestbold \bfseries \fi The \test@adj\ 
\test@animal\ said ``\csuse{test@\test@animal @sound}!''}}

\endinput
```

And the test document is:

```
\documentclass[em]{article}

\usepackage{test}

\begin{document}

\test

\end{document}
```

The `em` option is ignored and a warning is issued:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [em].
```

The only way that I can think of that will allow this option to be passed via either `\documentclass` or `\usepackage` is to define it with both `\DeclareOptionX` and `\DeclareOption` and then process the class options before `\ProcessOptionsX` like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\test@shape}{}

\DeclareOptionX{em}{\renewcommand*{\test@shape}{\em}}
\DeclareOption{em}{\renewcommand*{\test@shape}{\em}}

\define@boolkey{test.sty}[test]{bold}[true]{}

\newcommand*{\test@animal}{parrot}
\newcommand*{\test@parrot@sound}{squawk}
\newcommand*{\test@dog@sound}{woof}
\newcommand*{\test@duck@sound}{quack}
\newcommand*{\test@cow@sound}{moo}

\newcommand*{\setanimal}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{test@#1@sound}%
  {%
     \renewcommand*{\test@animal}{#1}%
  }%
  {%
     \PackageError{test}{Unknown animal `#1'}{}%
  }%
}

\define@choicekey{test.sty}{animal}{dog,duck,cow}{%
  \setanimal{#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\test@adj}{silly}

\newcommand*{\setadj}[1]{\renewcommand*{\test@adj}{#1}}

\define@key{test.sty}{adj}{\setadj{#1}}

\@for\CurrentOption :=\@declaredoptions\do{%
  \ifx\CurrentOption\@empty
  \else
    \@expandtwoargs
      \in@ {,\CurrentOption ,}{,\@classoptionslist,\@curroptions,}%
    \ifin@ \@use@ption
      \expandafter \let\csname ds@\CurrentOption\endcsname\@empty
    \fi
  \fi
}

\ProcessOptionsX

\newcommand*{\setuptest}[1]{\setkeys{test.sty}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\test}{{\test@shape \iftestbold \bfseries \fi The \test@adj\ 
\test@animal\ said ``\csuse{test@\test@animal @sound}!''}}

\endinput
```

Now the following two documents produce the same output:

Example 1:

```
\documentclass[em]{article}

\usepackage[bold,adj={giant killer},animal=duck]{test}

\begin{document}

\test

\end{document}
```

Example 2:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[em,bold,adj={giant killer},animal=duck]{test}

\begin{document}

\test

\end{document}
```

In both cases the result is:

[image: Image of resulting document]

Comment: IMHO, an advantage to pass `babel` language options in `\documentclass` is that they are taken in account by other packages e.g. `varioref`. Would there exist a convenient way for `babel` to list the loaded languages that could achieve this result?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I wish `babel` did provide a list of loaded languages. Last time I checked it didn't, but it would certainly help my packages a lot if it did.